# Tomahawk table parts

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, tomahawk

In many faces the paginator and column headers are part of the datatable. (Primefaces, Icefaces)

With Tomahawk its possible to use a datascroller for paging a datatable. And the datascroller is not part of the datatable. As seen in [Balusc paging and sorting example](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2008/10/effective-datatable-paging-and-sorting.html).

Unfortunately is the Tomahawk API not well documented and there are not many examples. So here is my question: Is it possible to use a datatable to sort the columns of another datatable?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question. In the end I used a normal html table and CommandLinks for sorting data in a backingbean.

Thank you for your time.